# Excel: Search for a project's size based on a specific date

Tags: excel, excel-2007

On sheet 1, I have the project's size the start date.  On sheet 2-5, I have the project size start dates for each phase based on the project's size.

Based on the project's start date, I am trying to search the size table to see if the start date is on or between the specific release date range.

I am trying to combine an if statement to select the size sheet then use something similar to 'vlookup' to through the dates to pull in the Phase.

For the first example on sheet 1, the Start Date is 9/7/2010 and it's Concat is SmallFeb.  I would then look at the Small_Proj sheet under the 'SmallFeb' column and since the Start Date is between Phase 2 (8/31) and Phase 3 (9/28), the result would be Phase2.

```
Sheet 1
Project         Size        Release     Concat     Start Date    Phase 
Project_A       Small       Feb         SmallFeb   9/7/2010      Phase 2
Project_B       Small       July        SmallJuly  2/28/2011     Phase 3
Project_C       Medium      March       MedMarch   9/30/2010     Phase 1

Sheet 2 (Small_Proj)
Phase      SmallFeb      SmallMarch    SmallJuly    SmallNov
Phase1     8/17/2010     9/28/2010     2/8/2011     6/7/2011
Phase2     8/31/2010     10/25/2010    2/22/2011    6/21/2011
Phase3     9/28/2010     11/9/2010     3/22/2011    7/19/2011

Sheet 3 (Med_Proj)
Phase    MedFeb        MedMarch      MedJuly      MedNov
Phase1   8/17/2010     9/28/2010     2/8/2011     6/7/2011
Phase2   8/31/2010     10/12/2010    2/22/2011    6/21/2011
Phase3   9/28/2010     11/9/2010     3/22/2011    7/19/2011
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a unique ID for Sheet1, then based on used that ID and the start date to search (using vlookup) the column names on Sheets 2 and 3.